# Contact Form 7 watermark for select menu

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

im searching for a way to put a watermark on select fields.

that is not working ->

```
[select* c_type class:ic watermark "choose type" "a" "b" "c"]
```

to put a not valid value that fail validation, i had to put `include_blank`

```
[select* c_type class:ic include_blank "a" "b" "c"]
```

but the problem is that i have `---` as watermark, thats what i want to change..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After hard searching i found this script that is working and replacing the "---" when targeting to that element
this one is changing all the "---"s

```
function my_wpcf7_form_elements($html) {
    $text = 'Please select...';
    $html = str_replace('<option value="">---</option>', '<option value="">' . $text . '</option>', $html);
    return $html;
}
add_filter('wpcf7_form_elements', 'my_wpcf7_form_elements');
```

this code, replacing with targeting

```
function my_wpcf7_form_elements($html) {
    function ov3rfly_replace_include_blank($name, $text, &$html) {
        $matches = false;
        preg_match('/<select name="' . $name . '"[^>]*>(.*)<\/select>/iU', $html, $matches);
        if ($matches) {
            $select = str_replace('<option value="">---</option>', '<option value="">' . $text . '</option>', $matches[0]);
            $html = preg_replace('/<select name="' . $name . '"[^>]*>(.*)<\/select>/iU', $select, $html);
        }
    }
    ov3rfly_replace_include_blank('menu-569', 'Choose language', $html);
    ov3rfly_replace_include_blank('menu-614', 'Choose country', $html);
    return $html;
}
add_filter('wpcf7_form_elements', 'my_wpcf7_form_elements');
```

hope that will save for some of you a headache
(source [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-set-include_blank-value-diff-than-?replies=4))

Comment: $select = str_replace('<option value="">---</option>', '<option value="" disabled selected>' . $text . '</option>', $matches[0]);

Awesome hack

Answer (score 34):

More recent versions of Contact Form 7 allow the use of first_as_label to create placeholder text that does not validate as an entry if users do not make a selection. Simply make your placeholder text be the first label in the list of options.

```
[select* food-choice first_as_label "Preferred food?" "Cake" "Pizza" "Burger" "Salad" "Donut"]
```

Comment: wow. It works. But in validation error it does not highlight as red. Any suggestions.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: @Habeeb don't forget to give " * " like this [select* name ... ... ]

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
[select* menu-206 first_as_label "Select doctor" "David Mikaberidze" "Sophio Gelashvili" "Maya Dolidze"]
```

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer as it's directly related to Contact Form 7

Answer (score 5):

If you find string replacement unefficient, you could simply use this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("select option:first").attr('disabled', 'disabled');// Disable the first value/label ---
  });
```

I also made sure that the first alternative is the "label" i want to use, by adding 'first_as_label' to the shortcode in wcf7, like this:

```
[select name first_as_label 'label' 'alt1' 'alt2' 'alt3']
```

By making the first option disabled, wcf7 won't confirm the form until this an enabled alternative is chosen.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with one line of jQuery.

> To replace the – - – with the placeholder text I wanted, I first of
>   all gave the fields an ID in the Contact Form 7 options. Following
>   this, I added the following in my themes footer between script tags.

```
$("#typeofinjury option:first:contains('---')").html('How Were You Injured?');//Replace ---
```

> The code simply looks for the first option inside the dropdown menu
>   which has the ID ‘typeofinjury’. It then replaces it with the text
>   ‘How Were You Injured?’.

The blog post for this solution with screenshots is [Here](http://harrisonproject.co.uk/my-blog/adding-placeholderwatermark-in-contact-form-7-drop-down/)

Comment: although i found the answer 2 months ago, it might be shorter way for someone else.

Comment: $("#typeofinjury option:first:contains('---')").html('How Were You Injured?').attr('disabled', true);        try this its work as actual placeholder and user cant select 1 value also  I always use this

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the following code to validate the email field domains in WordPress Contact forms 7**

```
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_email*', 'custom_email_validation', 20, 2);
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_email', 'custom_email_validation', 20, 2);
function custom_email_validation($result, $tag) {
    $name = $tag->name;
    $value = $_POST[$name];
    if ('***field-name***' == $name) {
        $allowed_domains = array('gmail.com', 'yahoo.com');
        $email_parts = explode('@', $value);
        $email_domain = array_pop($email_parts);
        if (!in_array($email_domain, $allowed_domains)) {
            $result->invalidate($tag, 'Please enter a valid email address.');
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```